# Using Python to remove the date from a series of filenames, when every filename doesn't contain a date?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm parsing a directory of files for databasing purposes. We have files with an almost standardized naming convention. Almost all are `name_of_file_yyyymmdd.py` or `this_name_is_longer_yyyymmdd.py` I want a return of `[name_of_file]`, `[name_of_file.py]` is ok as well. I attempted doing a loop (this part is functioning) and in my loop I have

```py
module_name = file[:-12]
```

This would work on the files that match the above style, but there are a few files in the directory which I can't rename with names like `noformat.py` or `who_needs_a_date_suffix.py` and as my loop progresses these names get blown up and return things like `""` and `who_needs_a_da` respectively.

All my searches have only returned info assuming all filenames are of a like type.

Since it's been requested here's the loop, that's leading to

```py
module_name = file[:-12]
```

```py
for k in range(0, len(df_temp.index)):
    file = df_temp.at[k, 'Python_Module_Name']
    print 'Now processing filename ', str((k+1)), ' of ', str(total), ', ', file
    headers = []
    with open(join(location_dir_input, file), 'r') as module
        for line in module:
            headers.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

    module_name = file[:-12]
    df_temp.at[k, 'Python_Module_Name'] = module_name

return df_temp
```

Comment: pls post your code

Comment: if possible, share the code you have already developed. It will help bring more context to your question.

Comment: Instead of blindly delete 12 chars, use a regex to delete only dates

Comment: What have you tried in other languages? Think about how you would do this with a shell script. If the underscores were a mandatory convention start with split()[0].split() and iterate to find a numeric in a range.  You can split on "." first, then "_".   Try it on paper first. If this is homework, consider what will happen for duplicates after the date is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do

```
module_name = re.sub('_\d{8}\.py$', '', file)
```

if you don't want to check the format of the dates

#### update

making the date optional

```
module_name = re.sub('(_\d{8})*\.py$', '', file)
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty close to what I need, but for the files that don't have the date at the end they're still ending as .py, while those with a date no longer have .py. So the final output of the directory read is still not in a matching format. I'm thinking I may need to go the boolean route and then maybe do a combination of what you suggested, and just a regular [:-3] for the files that don't have a date suffix.

Comment: This ended up being what worked, I did have to modify slightly by adding a second string ``` module_name_final = module_name.split('.', 1)[0]``` which because it's part of the loop, stripped out the .py from the few files that still had that lingering. Thanks! And I just saw your edit, so I'll see if that eliminates my need for my second bit of code there. And your edit made it much more elegant, than my version. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ".py" out of your result and the use the following code in order to check that the string you poses has the proper date format

```
import datetime

date_string_bad_format = '12252018'
date_string_good_format = '20181225'
format = "%Y%m%d"


try:
  datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
  print("This is the correct date string format.")
except ValueError:
  print("This is the incorrect date string format. It should be YYYYMMDD")
```

That way you can return True when it is a date file and False when it is not and decide what you want to do with the file

Comment: I'm not sure this would work in this situation, because the file name may start with additional characters besides the date. For instance, the string "file_20201112.py" would not be valid even after removing .py extension from the string.

Comment: I meant he should do file[:-12] and then remove .py
That will solve the problem you mentioned 
I wanted to give him a solution that would suit his code with minimum changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve your problem by using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). First you would check if the given file name matches a certain regular expression, and then process the name accordingly based on whether or not it does. A function to check if the filename matches a pattern would look somewhat like this:

```
import re
def ends_with_date(filename: str) -> bool:
    return re.match('.*_\d{8}\.py$', filename) is not None
```

If the result is True, then you could process the filename using the method you have already described. If not, then you could do something else.

Comment: This may have been a good road to go down, but given constraints beyond my control I'm on Python 2.7. I should have included that in the original question, apologies.

Comment: Oh, in that case you can remove the type signatures (str and bool) and the function will work fine.